# Android MediaCodec decode h264 raw frame

Tags: android, decode, android-mediacodec

I am using Android MediaCodec API to decode h264 frames. I could decode and render the frames on the view. My problem is the decoder miss lots of frames,especially the first some frames. **DecodeMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer()** return -1.   aAbout 150 h264 frames,just decoded 43 frames. I can not find where the problem is. Here is my codes.

```
 /**
 * init decoder
 */
private void initDecodeMediaCodec()
{
    mDecodeMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
    MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE,
            VIDEO_WIDTH_640,
            VIDEO_HEIGHT_480);

    mDecodeMediaCodec.configure(format,
            new Surface(mRemoteVideoView.getSurfaceTexture()),
            null,
            0);
    mDecodeMediaCodec.start();
    mDecodeInputBuffers = mDecodeMediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
    System.out.println("decode-----"
            + mDecodeMediaCodec.getCodecInfo().getName());
}
```

After decoder initial,I will start decoder thread.

```
 /**
 * 
 * @param frameData
 */
private void decode()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                ByteBuffer decodeDataBuffer = null;
                try
                {
                    //take h264 frame from cache queue
                    decodeDataBuffer = decodeDataQuene.take();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
                int inputBufferIndex = mDecodeMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
                System.out.println("inputBufferIndex: " + inputBufferIndex);
                if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
                {
                    ByteBuffer buffer = mDecodeInputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
                    buffer.clear();
                    buffer.put(decodeDataBuffer.array());
                    mDecodeMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex,
                            0,
                            decodeDataBuffer.array().length,
                            0,
                            0);
                    decodeDataBuffer.clear();
                    decodeDataBuffer = null;
                }

                int outputBufferIndex = mDecodeMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info,
                       1000);
                System.out.println("outputBufferIndex: "
                        + outputBufferIndex);
                do
                {

                    if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER)
                    {
                        //no output available yet
                    }
                    else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED)
                    {
                        //encodeOutputBuffers = mDecodeMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
                    }
                    else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED)
                    {
                        MediaFormat formats = mDecodeMediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
                        //mediaformat changed
                    }
                    else if (outputBufferIndex < 0)
                    {
                        //unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mDecodeMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex,
                                true);

                        outputBufferIndex = mDecodeMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info,
                                0);
                        System.out.println("inner outputBufferIndex: "
                                + outputBufferIndex);
                    }
                } while (outputBufferIndex > 0);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Anybody knows why?I hope your help.My android device is nexus 7.

Comment: I know it is a very old thread but mind sharing your code? I am trying to get raw h264 frames from a live stream and display it in my android app.

Answer (score 7):

Getting -1 back from `MediaCodec#dequeueOutputBuffer()` is normal.  It just means it doesn't have any output ready yet.

It's not the case that you hand `MediaCodec` a buffer of encoded data and immediately get a decoded buffer back.  You hand it a buffer of data, which gets sent to the `mediaserver` process, which feeds it into the hardware AVC decoder, which may still be initializing or maybe just likes to sit on a few frames.  When the decoding process completes, the decoded data gets passed back through `mediaserver` to your app process.

The trick is, the `queueInputBuffer()` call returns immediately.  In normal operation the input side of the decoder will run several frames ahead of the output side.  When you're done feeding input you set the end-of-stream flag, and when you see EOS set on the output you know you've reached the end.

You can find various working examples on [bigflake](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) and in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  The DecodeEditEncodeTest and EncodeDecodeTest examples work exclusively with raw H.264, the others use `MediaExtractor` and `MediaMuxer` to handle MP4 file wrappers.

Comment: I have look up your given resources, and I have some questions about this. **1) Is there any ways to make the decoder to decode frame quickly?** **2) Should I add the cds-0 which is the first encoded frame to the decoder format ?**  **3)Is the PresentationTime is must necessary?**

Comment: (1) You may be able to save some time by configuring and starting the decoder ahead of time.  I haven't experimented with it.  How much of a delay are you seeing?  (2) You can either add the CSD to the `MediaFormat` or submit it as the first frame with the `CODEC_CONFIG` flag set.  Don't do both.  (3) I don't think the codec pays any attention to the PTS when decoding.  (It *is* important when encoding though.)  If you're getting the time stamps from the source it's a good idea to keep them though -- e.g. in case your video source isn't providing frames at a constant rate.

Comment: The delay on my Nexus 7 is about 19 frames,  and 6 frames on my Samsung s3. The dalay is relatively stable. It seems have relation with the hardware ,but I am not sure.

Comment: @fadden do you mind having a look at my question please - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50817767/8199772